# TableSorter jQuery RegExp not working on IE7

Tags: regex, jquery-plugins, tablesorter, internet-explorer-7

I created a new parser for the tablesorter javascript plugin, which works fine in all browsers but IE7!

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'currencyXYZ',
    is: function (s) {return /[^\d]*$/.test(s);},
    format: function (s) {return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[^\d]/g),''));},
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Basically I'm replacing all characters except numbers from the table cell, right? If in my table cell I have **"from £500"**, it returns **"500"**, but on IE7 I'm getting something like **"1.09387348273428e+35"**... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  I'm very tempted to say 'using IE7'.  Is there any chance you could break it apart, dump out the return from the s.replace operation so we can see what that generates?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I wish I could stop supporting IE7........... I'm not supporting IE6 anymore and it has been a long battle... I've just changed to my original customised parser, and on IE7 I get only the last digit:

Comment: $.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'currencyXYZ',
  is: function (s) {return /[£,from\s]*$/.test(s);},
  format: function (s) {return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[£,from\s]/g),''));},
  type: 'numeric'
 });

Comment: I've tried a parse using IETester in IE7 mode ... even in IE6 mode, and noticed no problems.  I suppose there could be something funky going on with the character encoding, but I'm not sure what at the moment.  Any chance you could post a full HTML example on jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Sorry Jeff, there's more. My table cells look pretty much like this:

Comment: `<tr>...
 <td>from <a class="price" href="http://www.co.uk/aaaaaaa/bbbbbb/ccc.asp?aaaa=aaaaa&aaa;aaa=0-3&amp;aaaae=362&amp;aaa=362&amp;aaa=1&amp;aaaae=ssss&amp;aaaa=ssss&amp;aaaa=sss&amp;aaaaaaaa=01/01/2011&amp;ssssss=01/01/2011&amp;ssss=sssssss&amp;wwwww=3333333333">£103*</a></td>                          
 <td>from <a class="price" href="http://www.co.uk/aaaaaaa/bbbbbb/ccc.asp?aaaa=aaaaaaaa&aaa;aaaaa=0-3&amp;aaaaaae=362&amp;aaaa=362&amp;aaa=1&amp;aaaae=ssssss&amp;aaaa=sszzss&amp;aaaaa=sss&amp;aaaaa=01/01/2011&amp;sss=01/01/2011&amp;sss=sssssss&amp;wwwwwwww=33333333333">£139**</a></td>
</tr>`

Comment: So my first script is completely wrong, as IE7 was keeping the digits within the URL. What really intrigues me is that IE7 is the only browser not ignoring the html tag (the tablesorter plugin takes care of it). I use this parser in other pages, and they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try something like this instead?

```
format: function (s) {
    var re = new RegExp(/£([\d][\d,]+)/g);
    var m = re.exec(s);
    return m == null ? 0 : m[1].replace(',', '');
}
```

This will proactively look for the first value that conforms to `£\d[\d,]+`, returning only the numeric component.  You may need to tweak this if you support multiple currencies, international number formats, etc.

Comment: Jeff! It worked like a charm! Thank you very much!
I only had to amend the variable to `var m = re.exec(s);` to get it working! :)

Comment: Good spot ... I tested it in a harness which didn't use quite the same interface.  Bad Jeff.  I'm glad it worked either way :)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are passing a regex literal to the RegExp constructor function which wants a string. i.e. This is bad syntax:

```js
s.replace(new RegExp(/[^\d]/g),''));
```

To fix it, just use the regex literal directly like so:

```js
s.replace(/[^\d]/g,''));
```